# COALESCE function and to get the data from the supporting field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coalesce

The subject seems confusing like I am confused on how to resolve the problem in hand. I have a table TESTCODES with data

```
testcode1   testdesc1   testcode2   testdesc2   testcode3   testdesc3
SB00001         CBC         1234-1          CBC Panel   NULL            NULL
NULL            NULL            1234-4          XRAY            NULL            NULL
SB00002     'Culture B'     1234-2          Blood Cltr  989889          Blood Cnt
```

I have a query that gets me the TestCode from these fields:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TestCode1, TestCode2, TestCode3, '') TestCode FROM SOMEORDER
```

The coalesce works fine and returns the data as expected. But, I want the result to show which test code did it select. Eg:

```
TestCode
SB00001 - TestCode1
1234-4  - TestCode2
SB00002 - TestCode1
```

Can I do it with COALESCE itself or I need to change this query to use CASE statements?

Comment: I should have heard my heart, I thought that I should concatenate but somehow I always thought that the COALESCE works on the entire field + concatenated value. Thanks to everyone for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to concatenate the field name to the actual value.  You can do this inside the `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TestCode1 + ' - TestCode1',
                TestCode2 + ' - TestCode2',
                TestCode3 + ' - TestCode3',
                ''
               ) TestCode
FROM SOMEORDER;
```

The values that are `NULL` will still be `NULL` after the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it concatenating the fields with the field names:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TestCode1 + ' - TestCode1', TestCode2 + ' - TestCode2', 
    TestCode3 + ' - TestCode3', '') TestCode 
FROM SOMEORDER
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
 COALESCE('T1: '+TestCode1, 'T2: '+TestCode2, ' T3: '+TestCode3, '<none>') TestCode 
FROM SOMEORDER
```